# Automate updating DNS for Cloudflared Tunnel

Tags: docker, cloudflare, cloudflare-argo

I am happily deploying a Cloudflared Tunnel on Kubernetes with YAML that looks [like this](https://gist.github.com/scubbo/d3baee31a18dccfe8dac0677bb44b16d). This deploys the Tunnel itself just fine - however, updating a Cloudflared tunnel also requires [updating Cloudflare's DNS records](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/routing-to-tunnel/dns/) so that the domain name will point to the tunnel, and I'm looking for a way to automate that.

The `cloudflared` tool can do this when provided with the right arguments (`cloudflared tunnel route dns <tunnelID> <hostname>`) which suggests that I could carry out this pre-deployment step with an [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/), if I could parse the tunnel's config YAML and convert the list of domain names into commands. However, the `cloudflare/cloudflared` [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudflare/cloudflared) does not appear to have any shell available, so I can't do something like `grep '^- hostname: ' config.yaml | perl -pe 's/- hostname: //' | xargs -I {} cloudflared tunnel route dns <name> {}'`:

```
$ docker run --entrypoint /bin/sh cloudflare/cloudflared
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
$ docker run cloudflare/cloudflared /bin/sh
[ the /bin/sh argument appears to be ignored - the image continues with its usual behaviour]
```

This is particularly confusing, as `docker inspect cloudflare/cloudflared | jq '.[0].ContainerConfig.Cmd'` refers to `/bin/sh`.

I can see two paths forward here:

- Find a way to access `/bin/sh` (and associated tools; `grep`, `xargs`, etc.) from the `cloudflare/cloudflared` image
- Find a way to update the tunnel's DNS records outside the context of the `cloudflared` tool (I suspect I could use [this API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-list-dns-records), but using the `cloudflared` tool would be a lot neater)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Cloudycelt](https://twitter.com/cloudycelt?lang=en) for recommending that I build my own image to carry out this task as an `initContainer`. I've described the process [here](https://blog.scubbo.org/posts/cloudflare-tunnel-dns/).

I'm leaving this question open in case there's a better option that I've missed. I've also opened an [Issue](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/issues/739) on the cloudflared repo asking if this is a feature that should be added.